# tomcat server folder accessible to web client

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-404, directory, accessible

I don`t know how to set a folder accessible to a web client`s direct access.A Client needs to see some images or pdfs in a specified folder in tomcat server. When i hit the direct URL to the files, it returns a 404 error.

below is snapshot of tomcat webapps folder.There is no actual source file related to myapp.

[image: tomcat-folder-tree]

below is snapshot myapp folder.Here is the actual running codes.

[image: recruit-folder-tree]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the current location of the folder under your webapp?

Comment: @fmodos my app and tomcat webapps folder are in separate folder.

Comment: myapp : C:\Users\infox\workspace\recruit.


tomcat: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps

Comment: ok... I am assuming that your app is deployed in the webapps folder, right? what is the url that you use to access the folder?

Comment: @fmodos 

it is "http://192.168.21.27:8080/recruit/index" OR http://localhost:8080/recruit/index

Comment: ok, if you can please post a snapshot or list of the webapps folder and subdirectories... i need to see your webapp structure to be able help you

Comment: @fmodos i updated my question and inserted some pictures you might need to help me.

Comment: there is no recruit app in your webapp folder, you need to export on war of the recruit project and copy this war into the webapp folder of the tomcat